# Get session variable value using Moq..C#

Tags: c#, session, moq

.Net 4.6.1  C#

I'm using Moq for unit testing. I have session variables that i can set successfully using Moq:

```
Mock<HttpSessionStateBase> _mockSession = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
       Mock<HttpContextBase> _mockHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
   _mockHttpContext.SetupGet(ctx => ctx.Session).Returns(_mockSession.Object);
        _mockHttpContext.SetupGet(p => p.Session["windowsUsername"]).Returns("Joe Cool");
```

If I check the active session, the key "windowsUsername" is there with the value of "Joe Cool". Now I want to get the value of the session key I just created using Moq. This does not work:

```
 var name = _mockHttpContext.SetupGet(p => p.Session["windowsUsername"]);
```

How do i get the value of the session object i create using Moq? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set up `_mockSession` to return the expected value, not `_mockHttpContext`.

```
Mock<HttpSessionStateBase> _mockSession = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
Mock<HttpContextBase> _mockHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();

_mockSession.Setup(x => x["windowsUserName"]).Returns("Joe Cool");

_mockHttpContext.SetupGet(ctx => ctx.Session).Returns(_mockSession.Object);
Assert.AreEqual("Joe Cool", _mockHttpContext.Object.Session["windowsUserName"]);
```

Comment: Perfection! Thank you

Comment: I am happy to help you achieve the glory for which you are bound!

Comment: Haha! My username is a spiritual thing ;)